# Rebase vs Merge

Tags: git

We have two concepts in GIT Rebase and Merge

Rebase Overrides the history of commits

Merge keep track of history of commit.

Merge would be cluttered if many people works and commits on the same feature branch.

Rebase would be time consuming when multiple people commits on the same branch eventhough we just changed a few lines in the same committed file.

When to use Rebase and when to use merge in real time is not clear?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Use rebase if your feature is below the develop/while use merge if you've done your feature to merge your feature to develop/master. For more info check [this.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)

Comment: unable to follow the tutorial. is there is any good video is available?

Comment: any good video link or good link which is easy to understand would be better?

Comment: try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1f_luIO6Vc
or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_msiOrYLgM